# TypeORM many to many retrieve all relations

Tags: many-to-many, query-builder, typeorm

So, my issue may be a bit more complicated than the title suggests - I'm unsure how to describe this in a concise title.

Presume I have two entities with a many-to-many relation between them, `Question` and `Category`. In the database, the relations are defined in a join table. `Question` is the 'owning side' in this relationship - just like in this example: https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-many-relations/what-are-many-to-many-relations

Now comes the part I'm having difficulty with: I always want to return the category relations on a question, in case it has any. If I'm doing it through the repository, I can very easily do it with something like this:

```
let question = questionRepository.find(id, {relation: ['categories']};
```

it'll return the question with *all* of its categories.

This gets more difficult when I want to do it using the QueryBuilder. Reason being is, I'm trying to list questions with *all* their categories, based on an array of categories. So imagine the following data:

Questions:

1. QuestionA
2. QuestionB
3. QuestionC

Categories:

1. Category1
2. Category2

Relations:

1. QuestionA - Category1
2. QuestionA - Category2
3. QuestionB - Category1

Again, I want to fetch the questions with *all* their categories. And I'm trying to do this with the QueryBuilder by using an array of CategoryIDs in the where-clause. This is my current querybuilder:

```
let count = categoryIds.length;
let queryBuilder = questionRepository.createQueryBuilder('q')
    .leftJoin('q.categories', category)
    .where('category.id IN (:categoryIds), {categoryIds})
    .groupBy('q.id)
    .having(COUNT(DISTINCT category.id) = :count, {count})
    .getMany();
```

As far as retrieving all questions that contain the provided categories is concerned, this works fine. The problem here is I want to return *all* categories for the questions it finds.

So imagine if `categoryIds` were to only contain `Category1`, it would return both `QuestionA` and `QuestionB`. However it wouldn't return *all* their categories.

Even if I were to change `.leftJoin('q.categories', category)` to `.leftJoinAndSelect('q.categories', category)`, it would only return `Category1` in the `categories` array for both questions.

I have not been able to figure this one out, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Also, I was hoping to find a better solution, but for now the use of this syntax remains: `.leftJoin('relations', 'r', 'q.id = r.questionId', {}).leftJoin(category, 'c', 'c.id = 'r.categoryId,{})`

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you want to achieve. TypeORM gives you many options. Sometimes it is enough to use decorators in the definition of an entity.

```js
let results = questionRepository.createQueryBuilder('q')
    .leftJoin('q.categories', 'cat', 'cat.id IN(:...categoryIds)', {categoryIds})
    .getMany();
```

In other cases, you must manually construct the `ON` clause.

```js
let results = questionRepository.createQueryBuilder('q')
    .innerJoin('relations', 'r', 'q.id = r.queryId')
    .innerJoinAndMapMany('q.categories', 'categories', 'c', 
        'c.id = r.categoryId AND c.id IN(:...categoryIds)', {categoryIds})
    .getMany();
```